# Make Visual Studio start a project through docker-compose file

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting to know Akka.NET and there is a cool project that I'm trying to run in Visual Studio using Docker Compose.

Since it has a lot of dependencies and depends on several environment variables, I cannot directly run it without Docker Compose.

There is a `docker-compose.yaml` file in the project directory and the project is running just fine via the command `docker-compose up` (through cmd). However, I want to run the project via Docker Compose using Visual Studio? How do I do that?

How do I add the docker compose into the Visual Studio solution? There is no `docker-compose.dcproj` file into the project directory.

## [Project GitHub](https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-cluster-workshop/tree/dev)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Akka.NET, but I created a new console app and can add both docker and docker compose support via right clicking on the project and then selecting add.
[image: Adding docker compose support.]

In the picture, the *Container Orchestrator Support...* option will make a dcproj file for you.